# Calculate Retention Rate for Cohort Analysis in AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have two "tables" in Spice.

- Table A has all my user accounts including a created timestamp
- Table B has user activity with timestamps

Trying to build a cohort chart that shows

- Month created timestamp as **rows**
- Month activity timestamp as **columns**
- **values** for the respective intersections (*users with activity in February that were created in January* divided by *all users that were created in January*)

I tried *countOver* with *pre_agg*, partitioning by timestamp and a few other things but haven't been successful in getting the calculation to work.

Is this generally possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also been struggling with calculating retention rates in QuickSight. What I have found is that if I want to do these types of period to period comparisons, I have to do it outside of QuickSight.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a Heat map display for cohorts. To do this, create two new fields for the display. One for the month they joined, one for the retention time.

First, eg 'join_month'

```
extract('YYYY',{user_join}) * 100 + extract('MM',{user_join})
```

Then, add a calculated field based on the activity timestamp that has the time since the user joined. eg 'months_later'

```
dateDiff({user_join}, {timestamp}, 'MM')
```

For the values, use distinct count of users. This will give you the overall counts, and the visual is pretty useful, but it does not get the % retention. Users will have to work out the % from the actual users.